# Typography.Capitals not working on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, typography, smallcaps

For example in the following label I want to use SmallCaps, but they only show up on Windows 8 and higher. On Windows 7, there are just normal letters.

```
<Label x:Name="servername" Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps" Content="Server xy" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="15" Margin="10,0,10,31" Padding="5,0"  FontWeight="Light" Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SizeChanged="servername_SizeChanged"/>
```

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 and the font is *Segoe UI Medium* (and in some other labels *Segoe UI Light*), which is installed on both systems.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know, `Typography.Capitals` support is provided by the OpenType font family itself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.capitals(v=vs.110).aspx

> OpenType supports a number of styling formats for capitals, including small capitals, petite capitals, titling, and capital spacing. These styling formats allow you to control the appearance of capitals.

*Small caps support for Segoe UI was added for Windows 8.  The Windows 7 version of Segoe UI does not support small caps.*

https://littlenewthings.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/segoe-ui-gets-a-facelift-in-windows-8/

> The new Segoe UI also adds support for OpenType stylistic sets and ligatures which increases variation across the standard character set. **New features include small caps**, old-style and tabular (monospaced) numerals. In fact, the old variations of the characters above are included in the alternative style set (style set #20, in fact).

I'm unsure of the possibility and legality of packaging up the updated version of Segoe UI for use in your own WPF application.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know, there was a new version of Segoe UI implemented in Windows 8. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't know either! I guess fonts, as software, are subject to constant revision, too. :)